# Apache HTTPD (with SSL) + TomEE (Tomcat) null the ssl session id

Tags: apache, tomcat, ssl, apache2

Hello I have seen a strange behaviour in Apache HTTPD SSL and TomEE (in fact it is a Tomcat so it is exactly the same for Tomcat), I am configuring the typical Apache as frontend and TomEE as backend solution. Currently Apache is configured with SSL and with mod_jk it connects to TomEE using AJP. This works perfectly. The problem is that inside my code I need to get the ssl session id:

String ssl = (String)servletRequest.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.ssl_session_id");

I don't know why but sometimes this attribute is null and sometimes not. It may return a null at first then stay like 10 requests working and then stop working again during some requests and the get attribute returns null.

It seems that everything is configured correctly since sometimes works. Have you ever found something similar or knows what it can be happening? Do you think that maybe the problem is on client (browser) side?

Everything is dockerized here: https://github.com/lordofthejars/apache-tomee-ssl so you can review configuration files of tomcat and apache or even run it.

Thank you so much for your support.